# Overcoming data word length limitation of usbmon

Tags: linux, usb

When capturing USB traffic with usbmon, I sometimes see the following:

```
ffff8801ed3703c0 2599784347 S Bo:1:008:2 -115 74 = 24484880 087ffa7f dd7ffc08 d87fec7e d3000080 5e80a30c d1d43300 00803c9b
```

The data length is reported to be 74 bytes long, but the actual data word length is much shorter (32 bytes in the example above).

It appears that this is by design: Quoting from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt: "The length of collected data is limited and can be less than the data length reported in the Data Length word."

Can this limitation be overcome in order to capture all the data words?

Comment: Okay, I see there is a binary I/F that is documented in the usbmon.txt. Does this capture all data?

Answer (score 1):

There's a decent thread on this [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.usb.general/32235). USBMon's text interface is limited to 32 bytes, but the binary output will include everything, so you can use that. Wireshark is capable of understanding usbmon's binary format, as well as [Virtual USB Analyzer](http://vusb-analyzer.sourceforge.net/), or you can write your own tool.

I haven't actually tried it, but I have compared some small dumps taken with tcpdump to a simple cat of /dev/usbmon#, and aside from the pcap header, they're pretty much the same. I have looked at huge USB bulk data transfers in Wireshark, so I'd venture the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 0):

this reply is late but there is a utility for it
https://www.mankier.com/8/usbmon

> -s    Set the maximum length of USB data to print. The default is to print 32 bytes just like the kernel's text interface would. The
> capture size is automatically adjusted to match unless set explicitly.

https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/usbmon